# Handling progress change in a state

Tags: kotlin

I receive a progress which is a map<String, Int>. The map represents the files downloading progress with the file name.

This is how I receive the progress in viewModel:

```
  downloader.downloadFile(
                fileUrl = fileUrl,
                fileName = fileName,
            ).collect {
                setProgress(value = it.second, fileName = it.first)
            }
```

This is how I set the progress:

```
  private fun setProgress(value: Int, fileName: String) {
        _state.update { it.copy(progress = mapOf(fileName to value)) }
    }
```

this is the ui state class:

```
data class AppsUiState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = true,
    val isLogOutSuccess:Boolean = false,
    val progress: Map<String, Int> = emptyMap()
)
```

and this is my state holder:

```
 protected val _state = MutableStateFlow(AppsUiState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()
```

When I collect the state in my composable function, the state reinitializes constantly, it goes: 12% then 0%, 14% then 0% again, the same with other states.

Any idea of how to handle the progress properly?

Comment: You should probably show how you're collecting the flow and updating the UI.

Comment: Yes, that's most likely the problem. Make sure you `remember` the call to `_state.collectAsState()`.

Comment: Actually no I'm doing that exactly and the problem is still present

Comment: And also removing the setProgress function solves the problem. But of course I need that function, but in a way doesn't present this problem.